# Is $\mathbb{Q}(t):\mathbb{Q}$ normal?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Is $\mathbb{Q}(t):\mathbb{Q}$ normal, where $t$ is some algebraic element?

I want to say yes but I am not sure how to show it.

Comment: *Every* finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ can be written as $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ for some $t \in K$ (this is the primitive element theorem).  So your assertion is equivalent to saying that every finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is normal, which is definitely not true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. For example, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ is not a normal extension. The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is $x^3 - 2$, but $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ does not contain $e^{2\pi i/3}  \sqrt[3]{2}$ and $e^{2\pi i/3}  \sqrt[3]{2}$ is another root of $x^3 - 2$. Since $x^3 - 2$ is the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt[3]{2}$, every normal extension that contains $\sqrt[3]{2}$ must also contain the other roots of $x^3 - 2$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ does not.

Answer (score 1):

No. The simplest counter-example is $t=\sqrt[3]{2}$.